# Can't route Messages audio through Loopback

Tags: macos, audio, messages

Catalina 10.15.7

I have a chronic problem where the Apple ecosystem tries to be "smart" about where it routes alerts for text messages, which almost always means it routes it to the wrong device (between mac, phone, and watch) and I don't hear audible alerts for critical messages.  I always have headphones plugged into my mac, so if an alert plays there I won't hear it if I don't happen to have the headphones on in that moment - which happens a lot.

I wanted to route only audio from Messages, to my physical speakers, which would solve the issue.  Rogue Amoeba's software Loopback seems like it should to the job (**though I would love to know of a free alternative**), and it works fine for an app like Music.  But Messages audio refuses to route anywhere but my headphones despite setting it to route through Loopback.

How can I get Messages to route its audio through Loopback while leaving everything else going to headphones?  Also to be clear, Messages has no option for selecting its audio output device, so just adding a virtual audio device to the system, will not be enough.